# Object reference in interface part of object expression

Tags: .net, f#, object-expression

I'm trying to override an interface for a class in an object expression, but having trouble accessing the 'this' reference for the class I'm subclassing.

Example:

```
type IFoo =
    abstract member DoIt: unit -> unit

type Foo () =
    member x.SayHey () = printfn "Hey!"
    member x.SayBye () = printfn "Bye!"
    interface IFoo with
        member x.DoIt () = x.SayHey () // x is 'Foo'


let foo =
   {
     new Foo () with
        // Dummy since F# won't allow object expression with no overrides / abstract implementations
        override x.ToString () = base.ToString () 
     interface IFoo with
        member x.DoIt () = x.SayBye () // Error: x is 'IFoo'
   }
```

Bonus question: Can I somehow get rid of that dummy override?

Comment: If you don't actually need any override, then why create the object in the object expression? If an object is needed at all, perhaps it can be created on demand by the interface members. Hard to tell what's best without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @BentTranberg in my real example, Foo implements multiple interfaces (which clients may upcast to), in some cases I need on-demand instances of Foo that have one or more interfaces tweaked. I could, of course, just create new subclasses, but object expressions are much more convenient in some cases.

Comment: Right, but I am slightly unsure whether or not you are aware that object expressions don't need a class instantiation. You can have no class and only one or more interfaces.

Comment: @BentTranberg ah, no I am aware, I just need that Foo. I'm currently exploring different design patterns and since I've been off to C# land for some time now, my mind is very oop / interface focused and explicit interface implementation is just throwing me off (like this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast your access in `IFoo` so that

```
let foo =
    {
         new Foo () with
             override x.ToString () = base.ToString () 
         interface IFoo with
             member x.DoIt () = (x :?> Foo).SayBye () 
    }
```

Comment: The `:>` should be `:?>`, as this is a downcast. In this case we know it will never fail, but the F# compiler can't know that, so you have to use the `:?>` operator.

Comment: oops. what a difference a char makes ;-) Thanks

Comment: Ah, of course. Downcasts usually seems pretty dirty, but I guess this is just fine. I wonder why F# treats the object expression different than the regular subclass though..

Answer (score 3):

Cast your `x` in the `IFoo` interface to the `Foo` type:

```
let foo =
{
    new Foo () with
        // Dummy since F# won't allow object expression with no overrides / abstract implementations
        override x.ToString () = base.ToString () 
    interface IFoo with
        member x.DoIt () = (x :?> Foo).SayBye () // No type error
}
```

Comment: Seems like robkuz was a tiny bit faster, thanks for your answer!